# Why does [].append() not work in python?

Tags: python

Why does this work -

```
a = []
a.append(4)
print a
```

But this does not -

```
print [].append(4)
```

The output in second case is `None`. Can you explain the output?

Comment: if you do print a.append(4) you also get None

Comment: Whew! The Python community is lightning fast and so damn helpful. :-) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `append` method has no return value. It changes the list in place, and since you do not assign the `[]` to any variable, it's simply "lost in space"

```
class FluentList(list):
    def append(self, value):
        super(FluentList,self).append(value)
        return self

    def extend(self, iterable):
        super(FluentList,self).extend(iterable)
        return self

    def remove(self, value):
        super(FluentList,self).remove(value)
        return self

    def insert(self, index, value):
        super(FluentList,self).insert(index, value)
        return self 

    def reverse(self):
        super(FluentList,self).reverse()
        return self

    def sort(self, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False):
        super(FluentList,self).sort(cmp, key, reverse)
        return self

li = FluentList()
li.extend([1,4,6]).remove(4).append(7).insert(1,10).reverse().sort(key=lambda x:x%2)
print li
```

I didn't overload all methods in question, but the concept should be clear.

Comment: But that's not functional style. Shouldn't it return the object it operated upon?

Comment: Beaten by five seconds...*sigh*

Comment: No, `a` is mutable and the value of it is changed, there is nothing to be returned there.

Comment: @KshitizSharma If you need that, you could go for ``[] + [4]`` instead of append. Note that this would create a new object though.

Comment: @KshitizSharma Right, it's not "functional style", but not because it returns None, but because it mutates the object in-place. Returning nothing makes it less likely to be confused for a "funtional style" method that returns a new object, which would create aliasing bugs. Note that you really don't want to copy the list each time you modify it, as that's *horribly* inefficient. `list` sucks as a persistent data structure, there are better alternatives.

Comment: @delnan Okay. Do you know the class in standard library that actually provides the implementation for a list?

Comment: @KshitizSharma If by "list" you mean "linked list" (persistent or not), no, there isn't any. Just use `list` (which is a dynamic over-allocating array), or use a tuple if you want immutability (still no efficient updates though!). Both are less pain than using a linked list for no reason.

Comment: @KshitizSharma: You are referring to "fluent" interfaces, like in C#, F# and many purely functional languages. Python lists are not like this.

Comment: @delnan But if it returned the object even after modifying it in place it could support Java style Method Chaining and make the code much shorter. Is that outdated/bad practice?

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None` so that you "fail fast" if you make the assumption that a copy of the list is being made. Better to catch an unexpected `None` result rather than having to deal with two variables pointing to the same object when you didn't expect that at all!

Comment: @KshitizSharma It *could*, but it's not common in Python. Almost nothing in the stdlib does it, and most of the exceptions I can think of now are in APIs inspired by Java libraries, which are also non-idiomatic for other reasons. I don't know many third party libraries doing this either. Again, the reasoning for not doing it is clearly distinguishing mutating methods non-mutating ones.

Comment: referring to the edit, using ``super(FluentList, list)`` instead of directly referring to ``list`` is the way to go I think

Comment: Changed my code to your proposal, but with `super(FluentList,self)`

Answer (score 1):

The method `append` returns no value, or in other words there will only be `None`

`a` is mutable and the value of it is changed, there is nothing to be returned there.

Answer (score 1):

append returns `None`.

from your example:

```
>>> print a.append(4)
None
```