# Why doesn't [].extend(list1) create an identical list to list1?

Tags: python

The analogue for strings holds true:

```
string1 = 'abc'
''.join(string1) == string1 # True
```

So why doesn't this hold true:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
[].extend(list1) == list1 # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

`type([])` returns list. Why would it get perceived as a NoneType instead of a list which would have the extend method?

This is an academic question. I wouldn't do this is regular code, I just want to understand.

Comment: As a side note, you may think this feels funny from an API standpoint.  The difference is that strings are *immutable*, so string methods *must* return new strings.  lists are mutable, so list methods can be used to modify the object itself.  When the object itself is modified, it's preferable to return `None` to let the user know that the list was modified.

Comment: Python lists have no fluent interface, in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265589/why-does-append-not-work-in-python/14265608#1426560) I proposed a custom list type with such behavior.

Comment: This is definitely not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `list.extend()` modifies the list in place and does not return the list itself.  What you'd need to do to get what you expect is:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
cplst = []
cplst.extend(lst)
cplst == lst
```

The functions you reference are not really analogous.  `join()` returns a new string created by concatenating the members of an iterator together with the string being `join`ed on.  An analogous `list` operation would look more like:

```
def JoiningList(list):

    def join(self, iterable):
        new_list = iterable[0]
        for item in iterable[1:]:
            new_list.extend(self)
            new_list.append(item)
        return new_list
```

Comment: `cplst + lst == lst` is more relevant here, as it's more similar to what he does with the string.

Comment: @LennartRegebro -- I don't think it is more relevant ... While that will work, it doesn't explain why the inequality happens with the other form.

Comment: @mgilson: That explanation comes in the first sentence of the answer. The example is "What you'd need to do to get what you expect is". Using `+` is more similar to the string example.

Comment: No built in list operation (at least that I know of) is really comparable to `join()`.  `append`, `extend`, and `+` all act more like simple string concatenation (or flatten + concatenate) than `join()`.  I was trying to illustrate how you'd use `extend` to work in the way the OP was expecting; I thought that using `+` was more just begging the question (though I can see where you are coming from given that it creates a new list instance).

Answer (score 5):

Your're trying to compare the **return value** of the extension to the list. `extend` is an in-place operation, meaning that it doesn't return anything.

`join`, on the other hand, actually returns the result of the operation, so it is possible to compare the two strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> first = [1,2,3]
>>> second = []
>>> second.extend(first)
>>> first == second
True
```