# python list comprehension and extend()

Tags: python, list-comprehension, extend

Working my way into Python (2.7.1)
But failing to make sense (for hours) of this:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [3, 4]
>>> 
>>> a.extend([b[0]])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> 
>>> a.extend([b[1]])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> 
>>> m = [a.extend([b[i]]) for i in range(len(b))] # list of lists
>>> m
[None, None]
```

The first two extends work as expected, but when compacting the same in a list comprehension it fails.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What would be the expected right output?

Comment: "Expected output", you are right, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Oops, hit the return, my mistake. Expected output is [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], i.e. a list of lists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`extend` modifies the list in-place.

```
>>> [a + b[0:i] for i in range(len(b)+1)]
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. This comprehension can be assigned to a var m, which lists as you say.

Answer (score 4):

`list.extend()` extends a list *in place*. Python standard library methods that alter objects in-place always return `None` (the default); your list comprehension executed `a.extend()` twice and thus the resulting list consists of two `None` return values.

Your `a.extend()` calls otherwise worked just fine; if you were to print `a` it would show:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4]
```

You don't see the `None` return value in the Python interpreter, because the interpreter never echoes `None` results. You could test for that explicitly:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend(['foo', 'bar']) is None
True
>>> a
['foo', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 2):

the return value of `extend` is `None`.

Comment: Thanks. That explains one part of it.

Answer (score 2):

`extend` function extends the list with the value you've provided in-place and returns `None`. That's why you have two `None` values in your list. I propose you rewrite your comprehension like so:

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [3, 4]
m = [a + [v] for v in b] # m is [[1,2,3],[1,2,4]]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer: a list of lists, nearly hit the spot! What I need as result, however, is a growing list of lists: [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]].

Answer (score 2):

For python lists, methods that change the list work in place and return  `None`. This applies to `extend`as well as to `append`, `remove`, `insert`, ...

In reply to an older question, I sketched an subclass of `list` that would behave as you expected `list` to work.

[Why does [].append() not work in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14265589/why-does-append-not-work-in-python/14265608#14265608)

This is intended as educational. For pros and cons.. look at the comments to my answer.

I like this for the ability of chaining methods and working in a fluent style, e.g. then something like

```
li = FluentList()
li.extend([1,4,6]).remove(4).append(7).insert(1,10).reverse().sort(key=lambda x:x%2)
```

would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

`a.extend()` returns `None`.

You probably want one of these:

```
>>> m = a + b
>>> m
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.extend(b)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

Aside from that, if you want to iterate over all elements of a list, you just can do it like that:

```
m = [somefunction(element) for element in somelist]
```

or

```
for element in somelist:
    do_some_thing(element)
```

In most cases there is no need to go over the indices.

And if you want to add just one element to a list, you should use `somelist.append(element)` instead of `somelist.extend([element])